# indexOf depending on two keys

Tags: javascript, object

How can I see the indexOf when two keys have a certain value, in an object?

```
let myObj = {
"value1":[1,2,3],
"value2":[2,3,4]};
```

I would like to get the index of when `myObj.value1==1 && myObj.value2==2`, for instance. I can't seem to find the way to do it.

edit : well there could be :

```
if (myObj.value1.indexOf(1) == myObj.value2.indexOf(2)) {
commonIndex = myObj.value1.indexOf(2);}
```

But is there some more elegant way?

Also, how could I manage the situation where the value appears several times?

like here :

```
let myObj = {
"value1":[1,1,1,2,3,4,5],
"value2":[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
```

And I would want the case where `value1==1` and `value2==3`.

Comment: Can you explain the matching condition clearly. What two things you want to compare?

Comment: I don't really want to compare anything. I have an object, and I want to know where in the object two properties will get specific values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. It is more efficient. As `indexOf` takes `O(n)` time so using it once is better than twice.

```
var ind = myObj.value1.indexOf(1);
if ( myObj.value2[ind] === 2) {
    commonIndex = ind;
}
```

**Edit:** As I saw you edited the question and arrays can have multiple occurences of those elements. Here is my solution:

```
myObj.value1.forEach(function(val, ind){
    if(val ===1 & myObj.value2[ind] === 2){
        commonIndex = ind;
    }
})
```

Comment: Nice, thanks :) There might be some more complex situations, can you see my edit?

Comment: In that case you'll have to iterate through both the arrays. `indexOf` only returns the index of first occurence of that element.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I am editing my answer for your second requirement also so that the answer looks complete.

Answer (score 0):

This if is not good you could do:

```
if (myObj.value1.includes(1) === myObj.value2.includes(2)) {
commonIndex = myObj.value1.indexOf(2);}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use below code to get key from value of object

```js
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}
```